# Administrator Panel for express MonetDB application

Tags: express, monetdb

I have an express application that is linked to a Monet database. I need to have an administrator panel to monitor the app and see any changes in the database. Can I use some admin panels like the ones that are available on Rails (ActiveAdmin), or Django (Admin Interface)?

Comment: Providing code example can be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this helps, but several graphical interface tools are known to work with MonetDB to support click-and-go interactions: https://www.monetdb.org/Documentation/Cookbooks/SQLrecipes/Clients

Even if the tool you want to use is not listed there, connecting to MonetDB is fairly easy if a driver is available.  JDBC, ODBC are the mostly used, many more are supported: https://www.monetdb.org/Documentation/Manuals/SQLreference/Programming